# How to get OneSignal get userID in Cordova App?

Tags: javascript, cordova, onesignal

This question has been asked so many times but every answer is different and I've tried every single one of them.

With my code below, I can ask the user to allow the App receive push notes and it works.

But I'm not getting any device ID/userId once the user allowed the permission and I don't understand why!

This is my entire code:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', OneSignalInit, false);
function OneSignalInit() {




   window.plugins.OneSignal.setAppId("xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    window.plugins.OneSignal.setNotificationOpenedHandler(function(jsonData) {
        //alert('notificationOpenedCallback: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));

    });


  window.plugins.OneSignal.promptForPushNotificationsWithUserResponse(function(accepted) {
        //alert("User accepted notifications: " + accepted);

    });

    window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds(function(ids) {
                alert("player id: " + ids.userId);
            });

}
```

Can someone please advice on this?

Answer (score 1):

After a successfull OneSignal initialization, you can use the `getDeviceState` method from OneSignal object:

```
window.plugins.OneSignal.getDeviceState((state) => {
          console.log(state.userId);
        });
```